# How to pass pandas data frame between classes

Tags: python, pandas

There's 2 classes.
The **Content class** contains the data frame **df** that needs to be passed to the **Main class** data function, so that the dataframe df3 in the Main Class can get the data frame df from Content class. How can it be done?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd 

    class Main(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
    
        def data(self, dataframe_fromclassContent):
    
            df3 = dataframe_fromclassContent
    
    class Content(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
                
        def getcontent(self, para):
            
            df = pd.read_csv(para, dtype=str)
```

Comment: Passing it to the method data will be sufficient to get the reference in class Main.

Answer (score 0):

It's not super clear, what you want to do. A somewhat simpler example of what I *guess* you want to do is here:

```
import pandas as pd

class Main:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def work_with_data(self):
        return self.df.loc[self.df["name"]=="Anna"]


class Content:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = self.read_data()

    def read_data(self):
        return pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Dan", "Anna"], "age": [22, 33]})
```

And then:

```
my_content = Content()
my_content.df
```

|  | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Dan | 22 |
| 1 | Anna | 33 |

You create an instance of your `Content` class. Via `__init__` this will automatically call the `read_data()` method in that class. So your data is loaded and saved as an instance variable.

Then:

```
my_main = Main(my_content.df)
my_main.work_with_data()
```

|  | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anna | 33 |

Here, you create an instance of your `Main` class and pass the constructor (`__init__`) the dataframe from your `my_content` instance. Thus, the dataframe will also be saved as an instance variable of your `Main` instance. And the `work_with_data()` method can work with the dataframe.

/e²: Adapted to instance variables as wished by OP

Comment: Hi @mc51, can you kindly demonstrate how can an instance variable be set up in this case, thank you

Comment: @Codezzz you might want to look into [class and instance variables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3). It seems you need to understand these concepts a bit better

Comment: May i know for the read_data function, originally it contain an argument ie para, via __  init  __   how can i call the read_data() method in that class. As now there's an error shown "missing 1 required positional argument" thank you

Comment: @Codezzz I'm sorry, but I won't answer that. First, you should have made such points more clear in your question. Second, that's really basic stuff. You should really just look into some beginner tutorials / docs first. It won't help you to get all these basics delivered on a silver platter.